# “Falloir” vs. “devoir”: is there a difference in meaning?

Tags: grammaire, sens, subjonctif, infinitif

One is used impersonally (*il faut faire qqch*) whereas the other allows a personal pronoun (*quelqu'un doit faire quelque chose*).

However, *il faut que je le fasse* means *I have to do it* and *je dois le faire* means the same thing: *I have to do it*.
Other than the obvious grammatical differences (*falloir* + le subjonctif vs. *devoir* + l'infinitif), can these two verbs be used interchangeably, in this case, or are they semantically restricted to different contexts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La question est épineuse, mais dans ce cas précis, la différence est négligeable. En général, ce n'est pas forcément le cas.

Le TLF a une note un peu absconse à ce sujet

> II A.− Devoir + inf. a une valeur modale; devoir explicite une nécessité plus ou moins pressante à laquelle sont soumis et l'agent d'un procès et le procès lui-même (à la différence de falloir, impersonnel, dont la modalité n'affecte que le procès).
>   ([TLFi — Devoir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/devoir))

Autrement dit, *devoir* s'applique à un [agent](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B4le_s%C3%A9mantique#Liste_de_r.C3.B4les_s.C3.A9mantiques) et un [procès](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proc%C3%A8s_%28linguistique%29)¹, alors que *falloir* ne s'applique qu'à un procès. Ou encore « X doit Y » signifie que X doit réaliser Y, alors que *falloir* s'emploie sous la forme « Il faut Y » et signifie que Y doit être réalisé, sans plus de précisions. On pourrait dire que *devoir* est une exigence sur une action, alors que *falloir* est une exigence sur un résultat.

En pratique dans des emplois comme « Il faut X » où X est une proposition ayant un agent, soit du type « Il faut qu'Alan fasse la vaisselle » — à l'opposé de « Il faut qu'il pleuve », dans laquelle les *il* ne désignent rien —, le sens est presque le même que dans l'équivalent avec *devoir* « Alan doit laver la vaisselle ». La seule différence qu'on peut alors trouver est que dans le cas de *devoir*, on peut sous-entendre que l'agent (Alan) a un devoir moral de réaliser le procès (laver la vaisselle).

Ultime subtilité : on peut utiliser *devoir* sans agent explicite en se servant du passif, comme dans « Carthage doit être détruite ». Ça ne contredit pas ce qui précède, comme même si dans ce cas l'agent n'est pas précisé, il existe bien : nous, ou peut-être d'autres personnes, doivent détruire Carthage.

---

1. ne pas se laisser berner par les « Il doit pleuvoir demain », ce n'est pas le même sens de *devoir*, on passe là au sens II A 2 de l'article du TLFi, soit

   > 2​. La modalité affecte le procès; par le moyen de cette périphrase l'auteur du propos traduit l'aspect sous lequel la réalisation d'un procès est conçue par lui.
   >   ([TLFi — Devoir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/devoir))
2. ne pas se laisser berner non plus par les « Il lui faut partir », ce ne sont que des « Il faut qu'il parte » déguisés.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Très informatif.

Answer (score 5):

- *Falloir* is for necessities, needs.
- *Devoir* is for obligations, duties.

Obviously the difference between the two is sometimes just a difference of point of view and you may soften or explain an order by presenting it as responding to a need, or you may increase the chances that a need is fulfilled by giving to someone the duty to answer it.

Comment: C'est vrai que *falloir* n'exprime pas une obligation morale, mais par contre *devoir* peut tout à fait exprimer un besoin (« je dois partir, sinon je vais rater mon train »).

Comment: @Gilles, face à « Je dois partir, sinon je vais rater mon train », je perçois un implicite « et si je manque mon train je ne vais pas être à la caserne à temps ».

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples and points about the usage of *falloir* and *devoir*, *as per Laura Lawless on http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/devoirfalloir.htm*

> **Devoir** - When followed by an infinitive, devoir expresses obligation,
>   probability, or supposition.
>
> Je dois partir - I have to, I must, I'm supposed to leave
>
> Je devais étudier - I had to, was supposed to study
>
> Je devrai travailler - I will have to work

...

> **Falloir** is stronger and somewhat more formal than devoir; it expresses
>   necessity. Falloir can be used with an infinitive or the subjunctive.
>   Because it's an impersonal verb, falloir does not conjugate for
>   different subjects, so in order to specify the person who needs to do
>   something, you can either use the subjunctive or an indirect object
>   pronoun with the infinitive.
>
> Il faut travailler - It is necessary to work, One needs to work.
>
> Il me faut travailler, Il faut que je travaille - I need to work.
>
> Il ne faut pas manger - One must not eat.
>
> Il nous fallait manger - We had to eat.

...

> **When used with a noun**, falloir means "to need."
>
> Qu'est-ce qu'il te faut ? - What do you need?
>
> Il me faut un stylo. - I need a pen.

**For more information on devoir:**

http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/devoir.htm

**For more information on falloir:**

http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/falloir.htm

Comment: I don't perceive any formality differences between _devoir_ and _falloir_ (excepted the fact that formal speak tend to dampen everything and may use _falloir_ instead of _devoir_ for that effect).  And I don't agree with the notion than one is inherently stronger than the other, it's the driving force which is different.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Ok I can accept that. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Edited to improve answer and remove any dubious aspects.  It now just provides reference.

Answer (score 0):

"Il faut que je le fasse" and "Je dois le faire"

It's like asking the difference between : "I have to do it" and "I must do it".

Two ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score -3):

- **Il faut faire**: A vague obligation
- **Devoir faire**: A Must, a big priority

Comment: *Il faut* is **not** vague. It's very clearly imperative. Of course, contexts vary and there are degrees in this, but it's quite clearly imperative to anyone. You might refer to *Il faudrait*, which conveys exactly the *vague obligation* you're mentioning. The same use of conditional tense to soften the imperative sense is also true with *devoir* : *« Je devrais... »*.