# What is the exact meaning of "il y fallait songer"?

Tags: grammaire, sens

If I were to translate  *il y fallait songer* into English, I'd use “he had to think about it”.

What is a more precise meaning?

Comment: Translation to English is off-topic here, you can ask for further explanation of the meaning, but not for a precise wording into English (this would require specific skills and a certain command of English, which are relevant on EL&U but not on FL&U).

Comment: OK. So who can tell me if my translation is correct? Where do I go? Besides, I have seen many other questions here asking the very same thing.

Comment: Don't worry, we'll try to answer. But the phrasing of the question must avoid using “I need a translation of this in English” when what you want is to understand (and possibly reproduce). You don't need a reliable way to say this particular sentence in English, do you? About other similar questions, pointers?

Comment: Your previous questions (to some of which I replied to) were about specific idiomatic expressions, and showed efforts to understand the meaning from your part. But that's not the case of this question.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez "You don't need a reliable way to say this particular sentence in English, do you?" Of course I do. That's why I turned, for help, to this great community of connoisseurs.

Comment: Can't you figure it out by yourself if the meaning is well explained?

Comment: I can. _If_ the meaning is well explained. I thank you for your help.

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon Yes, you are perfectly right. This time I showed no effort in understanding that simple sentence because I put all my effort in translating it to the best of my current knowledge of French. Sorry about that.

Comment: @indoxica Do not be discouraged, your other questions have been quite good.  Sometimes it takes a bit of time to understand the Stack Exchange model. I recommend, if you have not already done so, read the help section thoroughly, post on the meta section if you have questions, and talk in the chat.  All of these resources will help you in asking and answering questions in the best way.  You are on the right path though.

Comment: Thank you for the pep talk. Next time I'll try to do better. Considering, however, I've only been on this site for less than two full days, I have so far done pretty good. Maybe we could chat, but I don't know how.

Comment: @indoxica chat: [Chez-cossette, french stack exchange chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette)

Comment: @indoxica 100 rep in just two days, you've been doing really good indeed! For quick translations like the one in this question, as mentionned by Patrick, the best would be to ask in the chat I guess, unless you want a thorough answer, with references and all, that could benefit future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, "He had to think about it" is an incorrect translation of this.

"Fallait" is the 3rd person past imperfect of the verb falloir.  **Falloir implies necessity and is only ever used in the 3rd person with the pronoun 'il'.**  This explains falloir nicely: [“Falloir” vs. “devoir”: is there a difference in meaning?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/falloir-vs-devoir-is-there-a-difference-in-meaning)

**"*Il y fallait songer*" would translate more like "*It was necessary to consider it*".**

**Other possible translations:**

- It was necessary to think of it
- It had to be thought of *
- It had to be considered *

*Notice that these last two translations change from the active voice, which is present in the French sentence, to the passive voice in English.  The 'it' in these two sentences is the 'y' in the French sentences.

Finally, falloir is an impersonal verb and therefore the 'il' in 'il faut' never translates to 'he'.

Comment: Thank you. As this site, which I found a few days ago, is my sole source of information regarding French and German (I'm trying to learn these languages on my own), any help, in whatever form, is greatly appreciated. For me, this community is the teacher of foreign languages I've never had.

Comment: I am glad I could help.  I am a University student in French and German.  You can certainly ask questions related to German but they also must be related to French.  You can even ask them in English, as long as your question is about German and French, and not just a question about German and English.

Answer (score 2):

The usual idiom is *il fallait y penser*. This means: this idea is perhaps easy to understand, but you would have to be quite clever to think of it in the first place. *Il fallait y penser* can have the literal meaning “someone should have thought of that”, or the idiomatic meaning “this is a clever idea” (but it cannot mean “someone was bound to think of it”, unlike what one of the top Google hits states).

Examples:

> *[Innovations inuites : il fallait y penser](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/054599229X)* (loose translation of “The Inuit Thought of It: Amazing Arctic Innovations”)
>
> *[Il fallait y penser — Une firme espagnole est en passe de commercialiser [une invention]](http://www.lematin.ch/loisirs/maison-jardin/leve-hop-lit/story/21444102)*
>
> [*C'est comme l'oeuf de Cristophe Colomb : Simple mais il fallait y penser...*](http://plus.lefigaro.fr/article/fraude-a-la-secu-sarkozy-veut-une-carte-vitale-biometrique-20120308-812724/commentaires/9074778)

*Il fallait y songer* is a far less common variant on this idiom. *Songer* here means roughly the same as *penser*. There is a slight connotation towards imagination in using *songer* (which can also mean “dream”) rather than *penser*, but the distinction is more of a matter of style than meaning.

Comment: Wow! It is exactly from a _l'oeuf de Cristophe Colomb_ that I took that little sentence. What a coincidence, indeed. Thank you. Your help is literally priceless.

Comment: I would say that in this phrasing *songer* may also connote cautiousness not only dream. For instance, “il y fallait songer lorsque vous étiez libres”.

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas d'un idiome: il fallait y revenir, il fallait y aller, il fallait y apporter une solution, il fallait y parvenir, il fallait y atterrir, etc. « Il y fallait songer » est ancien, à ne pas utiliser dans la langue parlée, « Il fallait y songer » n'est pas courant, plutôt littéraire bien qu'utilisable dans la langue parlée  et l'equivalent courant de la langue parlée est « Il fallait y penser.»