# What is the difference between "tu faudrait" and "tu devrais"?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

Both are translated (according to Google) as "you should". So what's the distinction?

Comment: One exists and the other doesn't, for starters. *Falloir* can only be used with the subject *il* and is used like this: "Il faudrait que tu ____." *Devoir* usually means "have to" or "should". At this early stage of learning, I don't think it would be helpful to pick apart the exact difference in meaning, since they're very close. If you're just looking for something to quickly plug into a random context, *tu devrais* is likely to give you much less trouble.

Comment: Does this help? https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/falloir-vs-devoir-is-there-a-difference-in-meaning

Comment: "Tu faudrait" doesn't exist. The problem with google translate is it always returns something, even if you type the most nonsensical gibberish. Maybe you should edit your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"tu faudrait"**

Verb: falloir

Verb type: Impersonal (similar to "pleuvoir")

Conjugation: Only with "il"; thus, il faudrait (conditionnel)

Example: Il faudrait que tu partes. (falloir que + subjonctif)

**"tu devrais"**

Verb: devoir

Verb type: Conjugated with all pronouns, viz., je, tu, il, etc.

Example: Tu devrais partir. (devoir + infinitif)

**Conclusion:**

Il faudrait que tu partes! = Tu devrais partir!

Answer (score 3):

***Tu faudrais is not French.*** You must rather say **il faudrait** or **tu devrais**. Both mean the same thing but not in the same way!

> **Il faudrait** = you give an *order* to someone.
>
> **Tu devrais** = you give a *suggestion* to someone.

Comment: I disagree with "il faudrait = order".

Comment: @Destal then what's the correct difference?

Answer (score 0):

'Tu devrais' is correct.  The other one doesn't exist, and should be instead 'Il faudrait que tu..'.  Bad google!!